# Where does docker ps Command look for current containers?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I need to know how it works and how it finds the current container and where it looks for containers by default.

Don't get the wrong idea of the question.
I am very familiar with the docker ps command.

In need this in order to be able to ingest other containers in run time without the daemon noticing the difference.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; the docker daemon keeps the list of containers in memory.
On a `docker ps`, there is no filesystem access needed.
On a `docker create/run/start`, the list of container can be derived from the layer found in `/var/lib/docker/aufs` (if you are using the [aufs storage driver](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/83f28cb374f6e08e2e929ea86833c0976ce47cf3/docs/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver.md))

[image: https://github.com/docker/docker/raw/83f28cb374f6e08e2e929ea86833c0976ce47cf3/docs/userguide/storagedriver/images/container-layers.jpg]

The containers themselves are under `/var/lib/docker/containers/{id}`
As illsutrated by [issue 15047](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15047), that path is loaded when the docker daemon is started. After, this is managed in memory.

---

[`docker ps`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/reference/commandline/ps.md) asks for containers in [`api/client/ps.go#L59`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/312c82677bdc86d50b483d642ad8c61f1c840c55/api/client/ps.go#L59):

```golang
containers, err := cli.client.ContainerList(options)
```

It asks [`api/client/lib/container_list.go#L45`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/803c7626ca076ddee50de5861531aa174e88e397/api/client/lib/container_list.go#L45)

```golang
resp, err := cli.get("/containers/json", query, nil)
```

That is managed in [`api/server/router/container/container.go#L34`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/87e7ee914261efd2580accae98569466f42cd003/api/server/router/container/container.go#L34)

```golang
local.NewGetRoute("/containers/json", r.getContainersJSON),
```

It then asks to the backend in [`api/server/router/container/container_routes.go#L48`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/64d70de0a2aa29f565336e896b76c23c879a9a98/api/server/router/container/container_routes.go#L48)

```golang
containers, err := s.backend.Containers(config)
```

Which is an interface in [`api/server/router/container/backend.go#L58`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/server/router/container/backend.go#L58)

```golang
Containers(config *daemon.ContainersConfig) ([]*types.Container, error)
```

implemented by the docker daemon in [`daemon/list.go#L83-L86`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/0f749ad55ab794872e601b4f665b07c0be07abfc/daemon/list.go#L83-L86):

```golang
// Containers returns the list of containers to show given the user's filtering.
func (daemon *Daemon) Containers(config *ContainersConfig) ([]*types.Container, error) {
    return daemon.reduceContainers(config, daemon.transformContainer)
}
```

The daemon has the list of containers: [`daemon/list.go#L37-L40`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/0f749ad55ab794872e601b4f665b07c0be07abfc/daemon/list.go#L37-L40)

```golang
// List returns an array of all containers registered in the daemon.
func (daemon *Daemon) List() []*container.Container {
    return daemon.containers.List()
}
```

From a [`contStore`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/0f749ad55ab794872e601b4f665b07c0be07abfc/daemon/daemon.go#L99-L102): [`daemon/daemon.go#L123-L132`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/0f749ad55ab794872e601b4f665b07c0be07abfc/daemon/daemon.go#L123-L132)

```golang
func (c *contStore) List() []*container.Container {
    containers := new(History)
    c.Lock()
    for _, cont := range c.s {
        containers.Add(cont)
    }
    c.Unlock()
    containers.sort()
    return *containers
}


type contStore struct {
    s map[string]*container.Container
    sync.Mutex
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, where exactly does it look for current containers in the file system ??

Comment: @WalidAshraf It is not in the filesystem (even though the images are kept in /var/lib/docker/). The docker daemon has *in memory* the list of containers. That is what my answer illustrates.

Comment: But it must have physical representation of this. in a file some where. or at least it scans the file system for them before creating the memory list you're talking about. I need to know to be able to add containers to this list by hand :D

Comment: @WalidAshraf your question was about docker ps (in memory processes): they are managed by the docker daemon. Regarding the filesystem, it depends on the driver's, but everything is under /var/lib/docker (/aufs for the default aufs union filesystem one)

Comment: @WalidAshraf the docker daemon does not scan filesystem on a docker ps: it has everything already in memory. It scans on docker run, when starting a container from an image (/var/lib/docker/images)

Comment: If its only in memory and docker doesn't scan folders or has current containers in some sort of file. How do you explain that a stopped - restarted docker service know all containers that have been used on this machine provided that i haven't changed my storage driver

Comment: @Wal my answer focused on docker ps (where the docker daemon is already started) I'll check tomorrow morning what happens when the docker daemon starts.

Comment: Thanks and waiting for your answer :D

Comment: @VanC Thanks but shouldn't it be the /var/lib/docker/container folder ??

Comment: @WalidAshraf Not exactly: `/var/lib/docker/containers/{id}` (containers, not container): they are loaded when the docker daemon start. No direct filesystem access (just for enumeration sake) once the docker daemon is started. I have edited the answer.